# Javascript setTimeOut unaccuracy, weird behaviour

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I need to time something kinda precise in the browser console. It sends a request to another website thats using pool.ntp.org to sync the own time. It would be good if its +-50ms. I know that I have some difference just because of my ping, but thats fine. I usually have a decent stable and low ping of around 25.
My first tests were with the timeout function, but this is highly inaccurate. Especially if you have to set bigger timeOuts for several hours.
Then I added a call of the https://worldtimeapi.org/api/ip for a more accurate start time. I also added a second call of that api 10s before the actual call to reset the timer and be more precise.
Now my weird behaviour.
I want to execute a function in 2h and 10 mins. So I set the first timeOut to 2h:9mins and 50 seconds. Then I call the current time from the web api again and set a new timeout from "executeTime- newlyFetchedTime".

I log all the difference times. And its kinda on point.
10s before the actaul call, I get the new current time. I set a new timeOut and log the new timeOut duration.

My problem is, I query the new time 10s before execution. I get back the time, I set a new time out. This is always around 8000-9500ms (so the first timeout was around 1-2s already off). After the new timeout is done, its executes the function. But its still off. And its not off by something random, its off kinda exactly by the measured difference from the first timeOut.

So if I measure a time difference between the first and second call of 1450ms, my execution time if off by around 1400-1500ms.
If the measured time difference is around 800ms, the execution is of by 750-850ms.
So somehow I have a bug in my code (I can't find it though, it is a pretty simple code) or there is some really weird behaviour from my chrome browser.

Here is the code:

```
const network_delay = 50
//execute the function at 2023.09.18 15:30:35:500
const executeTime = new Date('2023.09.18 15:30:35').getTime() + 500  - network_delay
const fetchTime = executeTime - 10000;

function fetchCurrentTime(callback) {
  fetch('https://worldtimeapi.org/api/ip')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      const serverTime = new Date(data.utc_datetime).getTime();
      callback(serverTime);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error('Error time API:', error);
    });
}

fetchCurrentTime(serverTime1 => {
    console.log("current time: " + serverTime1)
    console.log("fetch time: " + new Date(fetchTime))
    setTimeout(() => {
      fetchCurrentTime(serverTime2 => {
        console.log("time fetched again. now:" + serverTime2)
        console.log("execute function in: " + (executeTime - serverTime2))
        setTimeout(() => {
            executeFunction();
        }, (executeTime - serverTime2));
      });
    }, fetchTime - serverTime1);
})
```

I tried it with the animation frame also, but that doesnt work in background.
I tried it with a webworker, but since it is in the browser console, I have to make the code to a blod-url to call it, but in that code I cant access the document. But in my execution function I need to access the document.

And I would be fine with my current implementation, if the second timeOut is on point. Anyone has an idea how to "fix" that?

Comment: Well, `setTimeout` is not guaranteed to be very precise either...

Comment: Getting within 50ms or so is probably the best you can hope for. Not only is the browser itself doing who knows what other stuff, but it's running on a non real-time operating system that doesn't guarantee response times.

Comment: 50ms is the goal I want to archieve. And if the second timeOut wouldnt have the same time error as the first one, even if I make a new one, it would be fine for me

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe do something like this – periodically measure your time skew (if you trust that time provider) and take it into account for your delays, as well as the time it takes for your browser to get that time.

But as said, `setTimeout` is not guaranteed to be very accurate.

```
    let executeTime = Date.parse('2023-09-18T13:21:35Z');

    async function fetchCurrentTime() {
        const startTime = performance.now();
        const response = await fetch('https://worldtimeapi.org/api/ip');
        const data = await response.json();
        const realTime = new Date(data.utc_datetime).getTime();
        const endTime = performance.now();
        const fetchTime = endTime - startTime;
        return Math.round(realTime + fetchTime / 2); // Assume symmetric latency
    }

    async function tick() {
        const realTime = await fetchCurrentTime();
        const now = Date.now();
        const skew = realTime - now;
        if (now >= executeTime) {
            console.log("Ding!", realTime - executeTime, "ms late");
            executeTime = now + 15000;
        }
        const delay = Math.min(10000, executeTime - now - skew);
        console.log(`${executeTime - now} ms to deadline, skew ${skew} ms, waiting for ${delay} ms`);
        setTimeout(tick, delay);
    }

    tick();
```

Comment: Hey, this code has probly the exact same problem as mine. Its execute, its running over the limit, it should Ding!, but it doesnt. It runs another round. Here my log:
4941 ms to deadline, skew 101 ms, waiting for 4840 ms
49 ms to deadline, skew 98 ms, waiting for -49 ms
1 ms to deadline, skew 102 ms, waiting for -101 ms
Ding! 143 ms late
It shouldnt wait -49ms, it should Ding! afterwards